# OpenCV c++ cannot find <opencv2/face.hpp>

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, clang

I am trying to use opencv2/face.hpp. I am calling it in my code with this...

```
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
```

All the hpp files except for `face.hpp` work perfectly. I compile with this on my macOS Catalina:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 source.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o test
```

and I get this error:

```
RPPG.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/face.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
```

The weird thing is that I have `face.hpp`. When I run:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_4/include/opencv4//opencv2/
```

I see `face.hpp` and `face/` along side all the other hpp files I am including. I installed via brew and I think this is where clang is pulling the library. Why isn't it finding face?

Comment: can you check the output of `pkg-config --libs opencv`

Answer (score 2):

I see there are a few upvotes so posting my solution. I just had to edit my pkg-config paths.

Because I had the opencv version I wanted installed here (from brew):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_4/include/opencv4//opencv2/
```

I used this command:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/lib/pkgconfig/
```

This added opencv4 to my list of libraries usable by pkg-config. When I run:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

I get the same thing, BUT I now have opencv4, so when I run:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv4
```

I get what I want. `face.hpp` is included in this version.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using macOS. I would recommend you to use CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME YOUR_FILES)
#for example add_executable(Folder source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Be sure, that you have already installed openCV with brew (`brew install opencv`). To run your program after that your should:

- Create a folder in the downloaded folder project. E.g: `mkdir build`
- Execute cmake command in the build folder: `cd build && cmake ..`
- Execute make command to get a bin.
- Execute ./{NAME} to run.

Clang is default compiler in macOS. You should modify your CMakeLists.txt if you want to use gcc for example.